# Is there a way to separate data from one field in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

We have a drug column in our database and this contains the Drug Name (e.g. Xanax) and its size (0.5mg).

E.g. Drug Name: Xanax 0.5mg

However, there's a need for us to separate the two data without creating a new column for the size as doing so will have a huge effect on the database structure. We just need to populate a list with just the drug name without its size based from this single field / column.

Is there a way to extract just the name of the drug? Let's say by forcing the user to add a parenthesis around the drug size (e.g. Xanax (0.5mg))? Meaning just extract all the string that comes before the first "(" character?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**mytable:**

```
id  name
1   Xanax (0.5mg)
```

**Query:**

```
select id, substring_index(name,'(',1) from tb_mx;
```

Will return:

```
1, Xanax
```

So use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can store drug´s data in JSON format

```
{"some_unique_id":{
    "name": "Xanax",
    "quantity": "0.5mg"
}}
```

And then use [Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) for MySQL 5.7 to get what parameter you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with DB used in Pharma industry and I can say it's not ok do doit like that.

Here is what i think u must do (normalize)

Table UM (like mg,ml,etc)
Table Packing (like quantity per pice, pice nr , FK ID_UM) 
Table Drugs  (name, fk id_packing)

Don't worry about space. Tables UM and Packing will have alot of reused ID, and a column int take less that than varchar.

Or can used JSON ideea, but then you will have some problemes in reporting part.

Comment: Why do you think it's not ok to do it this way?